# How to get string from the result of BaseForm function

Tags: string-manipulation, number-representation

I want to get the string "b0.3ae"

```
In:=BaseForm[176.23, 16]
Out:=Subscript[b0.3ae, 16]
```

And then I want to get `176.23` by `FromDigits["b0.3ae", 16]` operation.

But I can't do this very well.

We also need to consider the case of this scientific counting method:

```
BaseForm[10045.21^6, 16]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fromBaseForm = RawBoxes[ToBoxes[#] /. SubscriptBox[a_, _] :> a]&;
```

**Examples:**

```
fromBaseForm @ BaseForm[176.23,16]
```

> "b0.3ae"

```
fromBaseForm @ BaseForm[10045.21^6,16]
```

> "d.9915"*16^("19")

Answer (score 2):

For your first case:

```
(BaseForm[176.23, 16] // ToString // StringSplit)[[1]]
```

yields

```
"b0.3ae"
```

which seems to be what you want.

It isn't clear what you want in the second case. A similar technique should work, though.

Comment: But this operation is not valid for `(BaseForm[10045.21^6, 16] // ToString // StringSplit)`

Comment: Yes. `StringSplit` yields four strings for that case (decimal exponent, hexadecimal mantissa, and two copies of "16"). You can use them as you wish, but you haven't stated what output you want, so I can't write the code.

Comment: I want string results in the form of `"d.9915" <> "\[Times]" <> 
 ToString[Defer[16^19], FormatType -> StandardForm]`

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this, but it's too complicated :

```
#[[1]] <> 
   If[Length[#] > 5, ToString[("\[Times]16")^#[[4]], StandardForm], 
    ""] &@StringCases[
  ToString[BaseForm[10045.21^6, 16], 
   StandardForm], (WordCharacter ... ~~ "." ~~ 
     WordCharacter ...) | (DigitCharacter ..)]
```